# Exclude supplied values from select using jooq

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, sql-except

I am trying to find a list of values present in a given list that are not present in a database table using jOOQ.

For example, I have values `1`, `2`, `3`,`4` present in my list.

The database already has entries for `1` and `2`.

I am looking for a jOOQ query that will return me the results `3`,`4`.

I understand this can be accomplished with the `VALUES` and `EXCEPT` terms in sql, and I know that these are present in jOOQ, and have been trying to replicate these, however the simple case explained [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/values/) for using values uses a static list (whereas mine will be provided programatically), and I'm not sure if *that* is the cause, or if it is the more general syntax. I haven't found a good example of `except` in jOOQ online.

What I've tried:

```
List<String> valuesList
```

```
create.select()
    .from(values(getRowsFromList(valuesList)))
    .except(select(TABLE.VALUE).from(TABLE))
    .fetch(TABLE.VALUE)
```

values expects a vararg `RowN` object, so I'm converting the values as such

```
private RowN[] getRowsFromList(List<String> rows)
{
    return rows.stream().map(DSL::row).toArray(RowN[]::new);
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field ("public"."table"."value") is not contained in Row ("v"."c1")
```

Using java 11, postgres 11 backend, jooq 3.13.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't have a `table.value` column. It doesn't even have a `value` column. When you use set operations, the projected column names are those of the set operation's first subquery, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT a
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS t (a)
EXCEPT
SELECT value
FROM table
```

This produces a table with a column `a`. But you didn't name your column of the first `EXCEPT` subquery, so the name is undefined (jOOQ and/or PostgreSQL may produce one, but I wouldn't rely on it).

The solution is to name your columns using a derived column list (the `AS t (a)` syntax I used above). This should fix your query:

```java
create.select()
    .from(values(getRowsFromList(valuesList)).as("t", TABLE.VALUE.getName())
    .except(select(TABLE.VALUE).from(TABLE))
    .fetch(TABLE.VALUE)
```

Comment: This did indeed help, thank you(!) - I had used the alias previously but I had obviously got the format of that wrong as well and it was also erroring, so I was trying to work with (what I thought was) the most simple version of what I wanted. Cheers!